# How to find typename within class template?

Tags: c++

I need to write some code so that an instance of my class template can find out whether its handling strings, ints, instances of another class etc. Is there a way to do this? I need to be able to generalize functions within the template class, without passing functions to instances of it.

Comment: Yes. Take a look at [`<type_traits>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types). Or, if C++11 is not an option, [Boost Type Traits library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Ah, very nice, thanks!

Comment: Showing results for: **I need to be able to _specialize_ functions...** (according to the data type)